# Related Queries web part; replacements in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: web-part, search

SharePoint 2010 had a nice web part available out of the box which could be added to search result pages to show users related search phrases, similar to this:
[image]

It looks like this web part is no longer available in SharePoint 2013 - I can't find any reference to it in the documentation, and the related search sections of the administrative panel look like they have moved or been removed.

Has this been replaced by something else, or am I missing something?

If it's gone, can you suggest an approach for building this functionality in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own by using the Search API (or REST) to look at Query Suggestions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn194079.aspx